# Android Room RxJava UndeliverableException

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I'm trying to fix some error reported by crashlytics in my app which I released to play store

I checked the log, but I don't know how to fix it...

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: 
  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError (RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual (SingleFromCallable.java:50)
  at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe (Single.java:3603)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeFilterSingle.subscribeActual (MaybeFilterSingle.java:40)
  at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe (Maybe.java:4290)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run (MaybeSubscribeOn.java:54)
  at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run (Scheduler.java:578)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run (ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call (ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
Caused by: android.arch.b.b.b: 
  at com.eastriver.workingtimer.data.source.WorkDao_Impl$4.call (WorkDao_Impl.java:172)
  at com.eastriver.workingtimer.data.source.WorkDao_Impl$4.call (WorkDao_Impl.java:129)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual (SingleFromCallable.java:44)
  at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe (Single.java:3603)
```

Actually, all my rx code is handling the error like this:

```
class MyIntentService(
        private val disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
) : IntentService("MyIntentService") {

    ...

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        disposable.add(
            workDao.getWorkById(getToday())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({
                    // my logic
                }, { t ->
                    Log.e(TAG, "error: ${t.message}", t)
                })
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        disposable.clear()
    }
}
```

And the WorkDao is:

```
@Dao
interface WorkDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM work WHERE id = :id")
    fun getWorkById(id: Long): Single<Work>
}
```

But I cannot find my error log in the crash report.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you add `getWorkById` subscribe to some kind of CompositeDisposable?

Comment: Oh sure, I edited this, could you re-check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks to me that `onDestroy` is called before `workDao.getWorkById(getToday())` is done. So it throws error while your subscriber is already disposed. What you can try now is handling errors from RxJava itself by following this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387916/2164363

Cheers

Comment: Oh, good! then I have one more question. If I handle the exception using the RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler, then "my logic" that should run after subscribe will not be run, right?

Comment: Your subscriber throws an error, so originally, it does not run `my logic` already, it would trigger `Log.e(TAG, "error: ${t.message}", t)` if your subscriber is not disposed.