# Got a Stackoverflow exception on Android RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, stack-overflow

I've been reading to the article [https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling) to solve my problem which is :

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
```

I know that this StackOverflow is caused by recursive method or function call, been trying to check which method that call itself over and over. Finally, I came up with this solution :

```
private class CastingDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Casting>(Casting::class.java) {
 override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Casting{
            val mappers = jp.codec
            val root = mappers.readTree<JsonNode>(jp)

            val type = root.get("type").asText()

            return if (!type.isNullOrEmpty()){
                mappers.treeToValue(root, getCastingClass(type))
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000)
                } catch (e: InterruptedException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                mappers.treeToValue(root, getCastingClass(type))
            }

.....
}
```

and before I only make the return like this:

> return mappers.treeToValue(root, getTransactionClass(type))

This method will be called by :

```
private val jacksonConverterFactory by lazy {
        val objMapper = ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

        ..................
        objMapper.registerModule(someModule)

        val castingModule= SimpleModule()
        castingModule.addDeserializer(Casting::class.java, CastingDeserializer())
        objMapper .registerModule(castingModule)

        objMapper .setAnnotationIntrospector(CustomAnnotationInspector())
        objMapper .registerKotlinModule()

        return@lazy JacksonConverterFactory.create(objMapper)
    }
```

I make a thread for the function to give some delay before calling it again. But I still face the same issue, does anyone know how to implement the proper handling here?, please kindly help me, Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525052/rxjava2-observable-take-throws-undeliverableexception does you trying this solution?

Comment: @rost I did try that, but didn't work out.

Comment: @rost this crash happens when there is data change manually from the server, before any changes, it looks fine

Comment: Can you show a class, where you using result of this call? I interested your disposable and work with it.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. It's too complex and pretty classified, but this class that I'm using is for the endpoint generator that will be called by every single activity class that needs to request data from the server and the method will be called by Jackson converter factory variable @rost

Comment: The thing is that this code works fine with other requests but only for showing a specific list of data, it throws an exception like above @rost

Comment: as you can take a look to my updated code above @rost

Comment: I assume that you are using your disposable incorrectly when calling request, but cannot help without additional information